# Outlook api choice for c# web application integration?

Tags: c#, outlook

I am building a c# web application which will interact with Microsoft Outlook.  When the user creates a Task in the web application i want it to also create a task in outlook.

The server i am hosting the web application on will not have outlook installed.

Which API should i use to create tasks in the users outlook?

Comment: is the client Outlook connected via an Exchange-Server (or office365) or just IMAP or POP3?

Comment: Some users will be using Office 365 and some will be using Exchange Server.

Comment: than use my approach in the answer! Fits for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Exchange Server or Office365 connected inbox i suggest
the EWS library:

[Get started with EWS Managed API client applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)